# rangeSelector doesn't show up

Tags: javascript, highcharts

When I add a series async to my highchart and `navigator` is set to `false`, the range selector doesn't show up and is not added to DOM.
When I add the series synchronous or set `navigator: true` the range selector shows up.

Is this a bug or is there a error in my code?

I provided an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kz44n38n/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add next code:

```
xAxis : {
            min: 0,
            max : 100
        }
```

Comment: This works indeed, but I don't think that this is a good solution. When I initialize my graph I don't know what the min and max value is

Comment: If you don't add some value for min and max, by default you'll get null and you won't see your empty charts.

Comment: I think it doesn't matter what min and max you use. It's only for first init. Then highcharts will update it automatically.

Comment: I had some strange effects with `min: 0, max: 100`. But it works good with `min: 0, max: (new Date()).getTime()`